# Android USSD programmatically not working

Tags: android, ussd

I was trying to send USSD programmatically using the below

`String smallTalkCode  = "*" + "808" + "*" + "13" + Uri.encode("#");
                        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + smallTalkCode)));`

but it is not working. I can see from the log debug that the # is replaced with %23. why is the Uri.encode("#") not working?

`12-29 23:06:27.092 16357-16357/com.example.tsf.myfirstapp D/TAG: *808*13%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my code was correct and the mistake was from the operator side. I tried to send *808*13# from the phone dial and getting the same error response. and tried to send another USSD short code which works fine using the below code. I was confused with the %23 output for the Uri.encode("#") at first. But it looks the # should be translated to %23 so as to work and # should not be used directly. I tried with

`String ussdCode  = "*" + "804" + Uri.encode("#");
  startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
  Log.d(mTtitle,smallTalkCode);`

and got the response I expected. plus from the log I saw *804*%23

thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Uri encode "#". Just use "#" simply.

```
String smallTalkCode  = "*" + "808" + "*" + "13" + "#";
```

Comment: I tried that but the # is bing ignored in that case. it comes like *808*13    with no # at the end

Comment: I ran the code and logged it. It comes out fine in the Log.

Comment: Yes I also logged it and it looks fine from the log but from the phone it is not doing the expected way. from the phone it displays as if you call *808*13 with no # but from the log you see it *808*13#

Comment: That's a little weird. Lemme see if I can get a workaround